# Печать машинного представления float

Tags: c#, python, float, ieee-754, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Есть стандарт IEEE 754 двоичного представления чисел и их арифметики.
В нем описываются нормализованные числа и ненормализованные. В теории все понятно. Но я хочу на консоль распечатать несколько ненормализованных чисел в их внутреннем представлении, машинном, т.е. с характеристикой и мантиссой.
Как это можно сделать, например, на Python, C#?
И еще попутно вопрос. Можно ли работать в языках высокого уровня с вещественными литералами в двоичной системе счисления?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Но я хочу на консоль распечатать несколько ненормализованных чисел в
>   их внутреннем представлении, машинном, т.е. с характеристикой и
>   мантиссой

На Python3 на основе ответа с [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16444726/binary-representation-of-float-in-python-bits-not-hex):

```
import struct
def binary(num):
    bins = tuple(bit for byte in (tuple(bin(c).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0'))\
        for c in struct.pack('!f', num)) for bit in byte)
    print(bins[0] + ' ' + ''.join(bins[1:9]) + ' ' + ''.join(bins[9:]))

binary(1.0)
binary(-1.0)
binary(1.175494351e-38)
binary(1.401298464e-45)
```

Отдельно выводятся знак, порядок (смещённый) и мантисса.

Для чисел двойной точности нужно заменить `!f` на `!d` и соответственно выводить больше байт для порядка:

```
import struct
def binary(num):
    bins = tuple(bit for byte in (tuple(bin(c).replace('0b', '').rjust(8, '0'))\
        for c in struct.pack('!d', num)) for bit in byte)
    print(bins[0] + ' ' + ''.join(bins[1:12]) + ' ' + ''.join(bins[12:]))

binary(2.716154612436e-312)
```

Чтобы перевести биты обратно в число, можно использовать такую функцию:

```
def binary_to_float(num):
    return struct.unpack("!f", int(num, 2).to_bytes(4, byteorder='big'))[0]

print(binary_to_float('10111111100000000000000000000000'))
```

Comment: Предложенная программа ненормализованое число 2.716154612436e-312 печатает как ноль: 0 00000000 00000000000000000000000

Comment: @Молодойеще потому что это не float, как вы написали в заголовке, а double.

Comment: @Молодойеще обновил ответ.

Comment: В Python тип данных float. Программа предложена  для Python. float в Python занимает 64 bits.

Comment: @Молодойеще вы же в первую очередь ссылаетесь на конкретный стандарт, там разве не так? В принципе, я добавил код и для такой точности.

Comment: Спасибо. Я именно стандарт и имел ввиду. Там 64 бита и 32 бита описывается, но в Python 64 бита. Меня интересует машинный ноль, машинное эпсилон и т.д. Отсюда и вопрос о реальном представлении числа в битах.

Comment: @Молодойеще `sys.float_info`

Answer (score 2):

В Питоне, можно [`float.hex` метод](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.hex) использовать, чтобы точное представление числа с плавающей точкой напечатать (как `%a` в Си (C99): `[-]0xh.hhhp±d`):

```py
>>> 2.716154612436e-312 .hex()
'0x0.0008000000000p-1022'
```

Если хочется байты увидеть представления IEEE 754 binary64:

```py
>>> import struct
>>> data = struct.pack('d', 2.716154612436e-312)
>>> data
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80\x00\x00\x00'
```

В виде бит это выглядит как:

```py
>>> import sys
>>> bits = bin(int.from_bytes(data, sys.byteorder))[2:].zfill(64)
>>> bits
'0000000000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

Так как [порядок `0`, то дано  денормализованное число](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8):

```py
>>> bits[0]  # знаковый бит
'0'  # -> положительное число
>>> bits[1:12]  # порядок (exponent)
'00000000000'
```

Денормализованные числа вычисляются по формуле: ±знак × (0+мантисса/ 2<sup>52</sup>) · 2<sup>1 − 1023</sup> (double):

```py
>>> significand = int(bits[13:], 2)
>>> hex(significand)
'0x8000000000'
>>> significand / 2**52 * 2**-1022
2.716154612436e-312
```

И в обратную сторону:

```py
>>> 2.716154612436e-312 .as_integer_ratio()
(1, 368167554019802297902961703073592265444961685287384386095984806211036520049665972495786961556290633771253993225976613596485201446531925242865351537949643006725668645734124513845866945743352000756639913885870091814580532597437363981258574050387614181710541845882032738795411959682006458992302809763070411033018368)
>>> _[0] / _[1]
2.716154612436e-312
```

Чтобы получить представление как: `f = m * 2**e`, можно [`math.frexp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.frexp) вызывать:

```py
>>> import math
>>> math.frexp(2.716154612436e-312)
(0.5, -1034)
>>> (1/2) * 2**-1034
2.716154612436e-312
```

Чтобы в двоичной системе дробное представление числа с плавающей точкой получить:

```py
>>> float_to_bin(2.716154612436e-312)
'0b0.0000000000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000p-1022'
```

См. [Преобразование дробного числа к двоичной системе счисления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/738774/23044).