# Преобразование дробного числа к двоичной системе счисления

Tags: python, float

Как преобразовать дробное десятичное число в двоичную систему счисления?

Answer (score 6):

### math.modf вариант: 0.5<sub>10</sub> = 0.1<sub>2</sub>

Если у вас на входе число типа float, а на выходе вы хотите получить это число в двоичной системе (основание 2) как строку, то можно использовать [`math.modf()` функцию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.modf), чтобы разбить число на целую и дробную части и вызвать [`float.as_integer_ratio()` метод](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#float.as_integer_ratio), чтобы представить дробь в виде отношения целых чисел, затем числитель в двоичной системе напечатать, с помощью `b` формата. Знаменатель является степенью двойки и определяет ширину дробной части в двоичной системе:

```
from math import copysign, fabs, floor, isfinite, modf

def float_to_bin_fixed(f):
    if not isfinite(f):
        return repr(f)  # inf nan

    sign = '-' * (copysign(1.0, f) < 0)
    frac, fint = modf(fabs(f))  # split on fractional, integer parts
    n, d = frac.as_integer_ratio()  # frac = numerator / denominator
    assert d & (d - 1) == 0  # power of two
    return f'{sign}{floor(fint):b}.{n:0{d.bit_length()-1}b}'
```

Пример:

```
>>> float_to_bin_fixed(-123.45)
'-1111011.0111001100110011001100110011001100110011001101'
>>> float_to_bin_fixed(-0.0)
'-0.0'
>>> float_to_bin_fixed(math.nan)
'nan'
```

### `float.hex` вариант в научной нотации: 0.5<sub>10</sub> = 0b1.0p-1

Чтобы получить строку в научной нотации (целая часть либо ровно 0 либо 1), то относительно лёгкий способ это злоупотребить шестнадцатеричным представлением:

```
from math import isfinite 
from string import hexdigits

def float_to_bin(f, 
                 hex2bin={ord(h):'{:04b}'.format(int(h, 16)) for h in hexdigits}):
    if not isfinite(f):
        return repr(f)  # inf nan
    # abuse .hex()
    h = f.hex()
    prefix, suffix = h.find('.'), h.rfind('p')
    return (h[:prefix].replace('x', 'b')
            + h[prefix:suffix].translate(hex2bin)
            + h[suffix:])
```

Пример:

```
>>> float_to_bin(-123.45)
'-0b1.1110110111001100110011001100110011001100110011001101p+6'
>>> float_to_bin(-0.0)
'-0b0.0000p+0'
>>> float_to_bin(math.nan)
'nan'
```

### `math.frexp` вариант

float уже хранится в двоичном представлении в компьютере. Можно использовать `math.frexp(f)`, чтобы разложить число с плавающей точкой на составляющие `f = m * 2**e`:

```
from math import copysign, fabs, frexp, isfinite, ldexp, modf
import sys

def float_to_bin(f):
    # NOTE: the implementation closely follows float.hex()
    if not isfinite(f):
        return repr(f)  # inf nan

    sign = '-' * (copysign(1.0, f) < 0)
    if f == 0:  # zero
        return sign + '0b0.0p+0'

    # f = m * 2**e
    m, e = frexp(fabs(f))  # 0.5 <= m < 1.0
    shift = 1 - max(sys.float_info.min_exp - e, 0)
    m = ldexp(m, shift)  # m * (2**shift) 
    e -= shift

    fm, im = modf(m)
    assert im == 1.0 or im == 0.0
    n, d = fm.as_integer_ratio()
    assert d & (d - 1) == 0  # power of two
    return '{sign}0b{i}.{frac:0{width}b}p{e:+}'.format(
        sign=sign, i=int(im), frac=n, width=d.bit_length() - 1, e=e)
```

[Пример](https://ideone.com/JU3ijg).

Ещё пример [разложения float на составляющие, чтобы IEEE 754-2008 binary16 формат получить](https://gist.github.com/zed/59a413ae2ed4141d2037#file-binary16-py-L20).

Все примеры в ответе точное представление получают, неточные вычисления не используются.

Answer (score 4):

На основе https://stackoverflow.com/a/7667448/4928642

```
def float_to_binary(num):
    exponent=0
    shifted_num=num
    while shifted_num != int(shifted_num):        
        shifted_num*=2
        exponent+=1
    if exponent==0:
        return '{0:0b}'.format(int(shifted_num))
    binary='{0:0{1}b}'.format(int(shifted_num),exponent+1)
    integer_part=binary[:-exponent]
    fractional_part=binary[-exponent:].rstrip('0')
    return '{0}.{1}'.format(integer_part,fractional_part)

print(float_to_binary(23.63))
```

Comment: @Qwertiy просто решение полностью взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666713/converting-float-hex-value-to-binary-in-python/7666995)

Comment: @pinguin, это не плохо, просто в таком случае это надо указывать в ответе (добавил ссылку).

Comment: Прощу прощения за такую копипасту. За добавление источника спасибо, код подправил под вопрос

Comment: стоит упомянуть, что код работает даже для денормализированных чисел таких как 2**-1074. Но это теряет знак у -0.0 (у float два нуля), и не работает для nan,inf

Answer (score 0):

Для перевода *целой части* можете использовать функцию `bin()`, например

```
bin(124)
```

дает `'0b1111100'`.

К *десятинной части* можете затем применить метод `.hex()` класса `float`, например

```
float.hex(0.515)
```

дает `'0x1.07ae147ae147bp-1'` - или `0.107ae147ae147b` (`p-1` значит сдвиг точки о 1 позицию влево).

Затем вы можете на одиночные цифры применить знакомую таблицу
(`0` - `0000`, `1` - `0001`, ... `f` - `1111`) на перевод до бинарной формы:

```
0.0001 0000 0111 1010 1110 0001 0100 0111 1010 1110 ....
```

(пробелы только для разборчивости). Пример кода:

```
import string

def tobin(cislo):
    celaja_cast = int(cislo)
    celaja_cast_bin = bin(celaja_cast)[2:]

    tablica = {hex(i)[2]: '{:0=4b}'.format(i) for i in range(16)}
    desjat_cast = cislo - celaja_cast
    desjat_cast_hex = float.hex(desjat_cast)
    desjat_cast_hex

    cifry = []
    for i in desjat_cast_hex[2:]:
        if i in string.hexdigits.lower():
            cifry.append(tablica[i])

    desjat_cast_bin = "".join(cifry)

    return celaja_cast_bin + '.' + desjat_cast_bin

print(tobin(124.515))           # 1111100.0001000001111010111000010100011110101110000...
```