# Перевод дробного числа в IEEE754

Tags: c++, c, float, double, ieee-754

В стандарте IEEE754 дробные числа представляются следующим образом:

```
 (-1)^s × 1.M × 2^E
```

где `s` - знак, `M` - мантисса и `E` - порядок.

Допустим у нас есть число `float f = 12.34` в памяти оно будет представлено так:

```
0100 0001 0100 0101 0111 0000 1010 0100
```

Как получить из него обратно десятичное дробное число понятно: старший бит `0` это знак, следующие восемь бит порядок со смещением равным `127`: `1000 0010`, то есть порядок в данном случае `3`. Мантисса `1.100 0101 0111 0000 1010 0100` что в десятичной системе равно `1.54250002`.

Таким образом `1.54250002 * 2^3 = 12.34000016`;

---

А вот обратный алгоритм мне не понятен как получить из `12.34` представление в двоичном виде.

Есть такой алгоритм: `12` в двоичной это `1100` дробная часть ищется так:

```
 0.34 * 2 = 0.68
 0.68 * 2 = 1.36
 0.36 * 2 = 0.72
 0.72 * 2 = 1.44
 0.44 * 2 = 0.88
 0.88 * 2 = 1.76
 0.76 * 2 = 1.52
 0.52 * 2 = 1.4
 0.4  * 2 = 0.8
 0.8  * 2 = 1.6
 0.6  * 2 = 0.2
 0.2  * 2 = 0.4
 0.4  * 2 = 0.8 //здесь началось зацикливание
```

и `12.34` = `1100.0101011101000...`. Но это явно не этот алгоритм.

В общем вопрос: как из `12.34` получить представление в IEEE754?;

Comment: связанный вопрос [Преобразование дробного числа к двоичной системе счисления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/738774/23044) (с реализацией алгоритма на Питоне)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это именно "этот" алгоритм. Только у вас в подсчетах ошибка

```
0.52 * 2 = 1.04 // а не 1.4
...
```

Так что у вас при правильном переводе получится

12.34 = 1100.01010111000010100100<sub>2</sub>... = 1.10001010111000010100100<sub>2</sub>... * 2<sup>3</sup>

А также надо помнить, что в памяти для типов `float` и  `double` ведущая единица мантиссы "подразумевается", т.е. явно не хранится. Мантисса в памяти будет храниться как

```
10001010111000010100100
```

Экспонента в памяти будет храниться как `3 + 127 = 130`

```
10000010
```

Все в точности совпадает с вашим фактическим представлением в памяти

```
0 | 100 0001 0 | 100 0101 0111 0000 1010 0100
```