# Почему при арифметической операции получаю длинную дробь?

Tags: javascript

Откуда хвостик дроби?

```js
console.log(1.1 - 0.99);
```

Comment: Чему вы удивляетесь? Вы где-то округляете дробь?

Comment: Всё из-за представления дробных чисел https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/770134/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B2-ieee754

Comment: Когда-то эта проблема называлась 2+2 = 3.99999999

Comment: @nick_n_a, тут это скорее: `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` :)

Comment: @Grundy, скорее как `(0.1+0.7)*10 = 7`=)