# Перевод дробного числа в двоичную СС python

Tags: python

Как перевести на python дробное число в двоичную систему счисления?

Comment: https://tutorialspoint.dev/algorithm/bitwise-algorithms/python-program-to-convert-floating-to-binary

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738774/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F человек вроде бы достаточно понятно объяснил, точно не знаю

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование дробного числа к двоичной системе счисления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738774/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)