# Помогите написать функцию, которая переводит дробное число с разными основаниями из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную

Tags: python-3.x

Для не дробных смог написать а для дробных нет

```
def binary(n):
    s = ''
    while n > 0:
        s = str(n % 2) + s
        n //= 2
    return s

n = int(input())
print(binary(n))
```

Comment: Ну, на нет и суда нет

Comment: покажите хотя бы что именно не получается сделать, хотя бы словами опишите ваш алгоритм - что именно вы собираетесь делать

Comment: Нужно чтобы программа переводила числа, например 0.625 или 125.625 из десятичной системы счисления в двоичную. Для не дробных чисел, я смог написать, а с дробными возникла проблема

Comment: Вот и приведите ваш код в вопросе. Вопросы про код но без кода тут не положены

Comment: def binary(n):
    s = ''
    while n > 0:
        s = str(n % 2) + s
        n //= 2
    return s


n = int(input())
print(binary(n))

Comment: Для дробных даже понятия не имею, как сделать

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738774/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Преобразование дробного числа к двоичной системе счисления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738774/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)